# Can't run Ionic on Android: class not found exception IonicKeyboard

Tags: ionic-framework

After building and running android app it closes.

Viewing Eclipse logcat it shows a class not found exception com.ionic.keyboard.IonicKeyboard

I'm new with Ionic and I don't know how to make it work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problems.
In my case the plugin **was already installed**, so I had to remove and add it again:

Try this in your app-folder:

```
cordova plugin remove com.ionic.keyboard
```

and

```
cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard
```

Comment: worked for me after changing name of an existing app

Comment: worked for me also and like @naoru, I too had just renamed my app.

Comment: Worked for me to after an upgrade of the Ionic CLI

Comment: npm changed plugin names. Now it should be  `cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard`

Answer (score 1):

npm changed plugin names. Now it should be
 `cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard`

Try this in your app-folder:

`cordova plugin remove ionic-plugin-keyboard`

and

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that plugin not installed?

Try in cmd:

```
cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard
```