# ionic android build succeeded but app stopped working

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

When I am trying to run app on android device using `ionic run android`, it is showing the build and launch as successful.

On device, it is showing

> app_name stopped working

I searched a lot and tried installing plugins again, not working. I'm not using  `ionic-keyboard` plugin. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: When I'm using `ionic serve --lab`, it is showing perfectly on browser with some of the plugins not working because browser doesn't support all the cordova plugins. That's fine.

`ionic platform add android` shows at the end

> saving platform to package.json file

Answer (score 0):

believe something to do with ionic-keyboard. can you try installing keyboard plugin once and checking the app if it works or not. Thus we will have some RCA.

[Can't run Ionic on Android: class not found exception IonicKeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383949/cant-run-ionic-on-android-class-not-found-exception-ionickeyboard)

Comment: Already checked. Not working for me. Also, I actually don't need that plugin. Still tried installing and running app, same issue. More detailed issue: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-succeeded-but-app-stopped-working/47475